# Ion-auth: Switching from an admin to a user account

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

I'm very new to ion-auth so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.

I have a feature request from a user (an admin) where they would like to be able to switch into another user's account to see the app from their point of view. The use-case here is that the admin would find the user in question's account in our user admin page in the app, then click a button to effectively 'become' that user.

Any ideas how this would be achieved?

Many thanks

Pete

Answer (score 2):

@Pete,

What you're asking for is what is sometimes called "hijacking" the account.

There isn't currently a feature for that, but essentially what you need to do is:

1) destroy the current session

2) rebuild the session as the user you want to highjack

3) make sure the logged_in session variable is also set.

---

Passwords are all hashed, but I think it would be pretty straightforward to write a login function for yourself that doesn't go through the password hashing as part of the login steps.

In other words,

1) log out

2) look up the user id's username & password

3) login directly with that password, not a hashed version

Of course, you'll want to be very careful about your security

Comment: Thanks for that. Damn. I was hoping it was going to be something as simple as "replace variable x in the session with y, which is the target user's id".

Comment: well, that's what it is, essentially, only being done more completely/correctly

If you look at ion_auth_model->set_session($user); I guess you could simply set a new user that way. Can't think of how it would break anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the users_groups table adding a "status" field, in order to set true/false the current user_group.

Then, upgrade the model with a function that makes the following:

1. Get the current group and sets his status to false.
2. Get the new group and set his state to true.
3. Redirect to home page of selected group.

With this change, you can regenerate all the user`s data session and navigate as the selected user.